# recovery does not process the goroutine inside the function in which recover is called

Tags: go

I'm trying to intercept a panic in a function that creates a goroutine that causes panic. Why doesn't the recovery intercept the panic, how can I explain it?

```
func TestRecover(t *testing.T) {
    fn := func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        panic("attack")
    }

    wrapRecover := func(f func()) {
        defer func() {
            if rec := recover(); rec != nil {
                fmt.Println("recover")
            }
        }()

        f()
    }

    group := errgroup.Group{}
    wrapRecover(func() {
        group.Go(func() error {
            fn()
            return nil
        })
    })

    _ = group.Wait()
}
```

Comment: "Why doesn't the recovery intercept the panic" Because https://go.dev/ref/spec#Handling_panics: "The return value of recover is nil when [...] recover was not called directly by a deferred function." Duplicate.

Comment: and what does it mean directly? If I don't call gorutina there, but an synchronous anonymous function, then the panic will be intercepted. I want to understand more about the device of the recover function

Comment: A sorry I deleted the wrong part. You cannot "catch" a panick from a different goroutine.

Comment: What the `go` statement does is creates a new goroutine tasked to execute the supplied function, puts it into some run queue and finishes. At this point, the code which has just executed that `go` statement has no connection to the spawned goroutine and has no implicit means to control any aspect of its execution; the two goroutines are completely disjoint and do not represent any sort of control hierarchy.

Comment: If you replace `group.Go(func...` with `go func...` you will see it more clearly. The defer is not in the same goroutine as the panic.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by putting the `wrapRecover` inside the `group.Go` call:

```golang
func TestRecover(t *testing.T) {
    fn := func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        panic("attack")
    }

    wrapRecover := func(f func() error) func() error {
        return func() error {
            defer func() {
                if rec := recover(); rec != nil {
                    fmt.Println("recover")
                }
            }()

            return f()
        }
    }

    group := errgroup.Group{}
    group.Go(
        wrapRecover(func() error {
            fn()
            return nil
        }),
    )

    _ = group.Wait()
}
```

That way the recover is in the same goroutine as the panic.

There a runnable [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/qjdWSpi5LZ4).